# Changing a form value or input field value during the submit handler

Tags: ajax, forms

I am trying to change the value of a text area field at the end of my submit handler. I have tried using `form_set_value` and `$form['form_id']['#value'] = 'something';` to accomplish this but after clicking the submit button the field never changes. Also the submit button that I am trying to change the field with comes from the file managed form. I also included `$form_state['rebuild'] = true;` after I set the field's value. Here is my code

```
function my_module_my_form_submit($form,&$form_state) {

//do something with then file code
...
```

then

```
$form_set_value($form['value_to_change'], 'update the value, $form_state);
```

//I also tried

```
$form['value_to_change']['#value'] = 'update the value';

$form_state['rebuild'] =TRUE
}
```

In the form my code is

```
$form['value_to_change'] = array(
'#type' = 'text area',
'#value' => 'this will change',
);
```

Comment: Try `$form_state['values']['YOURFIELD']` it should be working

Comment: Generally accepted place for changing form is validator, not submit handler. Is there any particular reason to do it on submit?

Answer (score 3):

Just stumbled upon this and it's pretty dead so here's the answer in case OP still cares... turns out @Mołot is right.

The correct way to programatically change a form's submitted value is actually during validation and not during submission.

If you go back and re-read the documentation for [form_set_value()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_value/7), you'll notice that it explicitly says:

> Changes submitted form values during form validation.